# Time performance

Tags: java, performance

Hi
I have a question that this is my class which for each "n" will get the average time for it.
also the method that I want to take its performance has T(n)= O(nlogn)

my code :

```
public class NewClass1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Point> randList = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for (int n = 100; n <= 500; n+=200) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                Point point = new Point(rand.nextInt(10), rand.nextInt(10));
                randList.add(point);
            }
            get(randList);
        }
    }

    public static void get(List<Point> list) {
        long time = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<10;i++) {
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            GrahamVersion.grahamScan(list);

            long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            time = time+t0-t;
        }
        System.out.println((double)time/10);
    }
}
```

and it will print:

```
1.5
1.6
0.0
```

the average time is OK? because for `n = 500` will have `0.0` and for `n = 300` will have `1.6`

Comment: in that method I used a sort method which has T(n) = O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

A number of things that are / may be causing "strange" results.

First, your benchmarking is not taking account of the need to "warm up" the JVM.  You should put a big loop around the benchmark code and run it a number of times until the numbers seem to stabilize.  For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
      List<Point> randList = new ArrayList<Point>();
      for (int n = 100; n <= 500; n+=200) {
        ...
      }
    }
}
```

(By running the benchmark in a loop like this, you give the JVM a chance to load and compile the code classes to native code, so that your results are not distorted by the overheads of class loading, JIT compilation and so on.)

Second, you should be printing the results with greater precision.

Third, you should be looking at more than just 3 datapoints.

Finally, you may have fallen into the trap of assuming that big O allows you to predict behavior with small values of `N`.  This is not correct.  It *only* tells you what happens as `N` tends to infinity.  And even then, it only tells you the upper bound performance.

Comment: I can not get the a big for loop! where should I put it? could you please put it in my code in your post?

Comment: I get it.also I have question that if I take the time as nonoTime() the answer will be like 2974037,7247038,18033409 is it OK?

Comment: If you run the tst multiple times, how much variation do you see?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the test for at least 2 seconds before you will get reproduceable results.  Your test runs so fast that your can't measure it with currentTimeMillis, I suggest using System.nanoTime(), after you have run the test for 2 secs.